# Initialization Vector (IV) - update frequency

Tags: encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

This is a pretty straightforward question which concerns the initialization vector (IV), when using symmetric encryption (e.g. AES) togheter with say CBC.

My question: Should the IV change for each new plaintext or does it suffice to create one for each new session?

At the moment im using java for my implementation and the Cipher Class, and i noticed that it indeed creates a new IV first time, however that same IV is also used for later plaintexts as well.

Perhaps there is some reading resources about this topic?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: this answer is only about the IV in CBC mode encryption.*

You need to create a new IV for each separate encryption "session" with the same key. For an IV to be cryptographically secure it should be indistinquishable from a random number to the attacker. Java by default uses a zero IV, which means you should not reuse the key to create other cipher texts.

So no, you should not reuse the session without setting a new IV. Basically, the only thing that is secure for any protocol is the source below. There are ways of creating  a secure IV using other information in a protocol, but I won't go into that.

```java
Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

// repeat this for each cipher text
byte[] ivBytes = new byte[aes.getBlockSize()];
SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
rnd.nextBytes(ivBytes);
aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

// now prepend the ivBytes to the output, e.g. by writing it to a stream first
// remove and use as IV at the receiving side
```

[EDIT]: Forgot about the shorthand notation for this:

```java
aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk, new SecureRandom());
byte[] ivBytes = aes.getIV();
```

Note that the code above does not provide integrity protection.

Comment: Note that Java does not always have the most ellegant API regarding encryption, as it is likely that it spuriously performs the key expansion methods each time you call init.

Comment: Thanks! i ended up using the same shorthand notation you suggested.

Comment: Beware of padding oracle attacks though, CBC does not protect against it and it would mean your plain text could be made visible to an attacker in about *128 tries per byte*.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes if CBC does not protect agains padding oracle attacks, what should I use? What's the safest encryption option? Thanks.

Comment: For Java GCM mode is implemented, which offers authentication / integrity protection of the ciphertext and therefore plaintext. It's a mode with an integrated MAC. It doesn't require padding at all, but it does output an authentication tag within the ciphertext (in the Java interpretation the tag is part of the ciphertext).

Answer (score 4):

In CBC, for maximum security the IV must be unpredictable.

```
Should the IV change for each new plaintext or
does it suffice to create one for each new session?
```

It's not totally clear to me the meaning you give to "*plaintext*" and to "*session*".

If you mean that for each session there is a new, fresh key, and that the data exchanged is chopped up in pieces and then encrypted, then CBC will be typically applied to the whole chain of pieces, meaning that the ciphertext block of piece P<sub>n-1</sub> can be used as IV for piece P<sub>n</sub>. You therefore need only one IV for the whole session.

```
Perhaps there is some reading resources about this topic?
```

Sure, [NIST SP 800-38A](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf), section 6.2.

Comment: I think "session" means each set of N times `update()` and single `doFinal()` method call. Could me_L_coding confirm?

Comment: Yes, pardon me for the confusion; with session i do mean what owlstead (above this comment) interpreted it as.